# i got this error while im launching my robot

Tags: gazebo, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Error:

```
[gzclient   -2] gzclient: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:734: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::rendering::Camera; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = gazebo::rendering::Camera*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
[gzclient   -2] Aborted
[ERROR] [gzclient   -2]: process has died [pid 3246, exit code 134, cmd 'gzclient   '].
```

Launch file:

```
# Start Gazebo server
  start_gazebo_server_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(pkg_gazebo_ros, 'launch', 'gzserver.launch.py')),
    condition=IfCondition(use_simulator),
    launch_arguments={'world': world}.items())

  # Start Gazebo client    
  start_gazebo_client_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(pkg_gazebo_ros, 'launch', 'gzclient.launch.py')),
    condition=IfCondition(PythonExpression([use_simulator, ' and not ', headless])))
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400485/i-got-this-error-while-im-launching-my-robot/) by [iimata](https://answers.ros.org/users/101281/iimata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2022-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on [this related question and it's answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/358847/cannot-launch-gzclient-on-a-launch-file-results-in-shared_ptr-assertion-error/):

> Could you try sourcing Gazebo's setup
> after sourcing your workspace? `. /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh`
> This is needed to set some necessary
> environment variables in case they're
> going to be overridden, which is a
> common use case. More context in this
> [issue](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/1949).

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iimata](https://answers.ros.org/users/101281/iimata/) on 2022-05-13**:
thank you,its worked <3

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-13**:
Please accept this answer so the question is marked as solved then :)